# Remove white spaces from string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a column that looks like the below

```
  [ItemName]
  Monitor      5      £100
```

I need to delete any unnecessary spaces so my output would look like the below

```
  [ItemName]
  Monitor 5 £100
```

I have tried the below code however this doesn't work and nothing in the output changes

```
 REPLACE([Itemname],CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'')  FROM tbl
```

I replaced the '' with '-' to see which spaces it is replacing and I get the below

```
  [ItemName]
  Monitor--  -  - -5--  - -£100--
```

So it looks like my query isn't picking up all of the spaces correctly? Is there something obvious I am missing off?

Appreciate any help
Jess

Comment: Your `REPLACE` is changing only cr/lf sequences. Other whitespace may be tabs, spaces, line-feed (without preceeding carriage return), etc.

Comment: Your text may include `tab` (char(9)), separate `cr` and `lf` and `non-breaking space` (char(160)) - you should replace them all. There can be many more invisible symbols, but those four are most common.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem, **copying** the data you provided. All those spaces you provided in the example **are** spaces. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=33e945305ce283ad44beecf1f1999699)

Comment: How about `REPLACE([Itemname], '  ', ' ')`?

Comment: Arvo your suggestion worked! It was the non-breaking spaces I was missing out. Thank you so much